# mdb debugging "::panicinfo': unknown dcmd name"

Tags: debugging, unix, solaris

Im trying to find the reason of a Segmentation fault using mdb debugger.
When I try

::panicinfo,

::ps,

it gives the following error

mdb: invalid command '::panicinfo': unknown dcmd name

mdb: invalid command '::ps': unknown dcmd name

But they are valid commands aren't they?

Do I need to load some libraries for this?

Comment: How are you launching mdb ?

Comment: I launch as
>> mdb <program> <core dump>.

mdb commands ::status, ::stack are working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::ps` and `::panicinfo` are valid dcmds but only for the kernel modular debugger (`mdb -k`).

They are only meaningful when examining a kernel, and more specifically a post mortem crash dump for the latter. A process core dump doesn't contain a process table and a panic situation can only occur in a kernel crash, not a process crash.

You might simply run `pstack core` to get a stack back-trace of your crashed process.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might want to try is to utter

```
::status
```

when you're looking at your core file. Then you could walk the thread list and see what's going on - generally pretty easy to see which thread copped the fault:

```
$ mdb core.isapython2.6.7778 
Loading modules: [ libc.so.1 libpython2.6.so.1.0 libnvpair.so.1
libsysevent.so.1 libcmdutils.so.1 libavl.so.1 libuutil.so.1
libumem.so.1 ld.so.1 ]
> ::status
debugging core file of isapython2.6 (32-bit) from limoncello
file: /usr/bin/i86/isapython2.6
initial argv: python
threading model: native threads
status: process terminated by SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault), addr=b2b118f4
> ::walk thread |::findstack -v
stack pointer for thread 1: f13165ac
[ f13165ac libc_hwcap1.so.1`strlen+0x30() ]
  f13165b8 libffi.so.5.0.10`ffi_call_SYSV+0x17(7213a40, f13165e0, 4, 1,     f13166a0, 71a45a8)
  f13165f8 libffi.so.5.0.10`ffi_call+0x74(f1316620, 71a45a8, f13166a0,  f1316690)
  f1316658 _ctypes.so`_call_function_pointer+0xe1(1109, 71a45a8, f1316690, f1316680, 8b6bf54, f13166a0)
  f1316718 _ctypes.so`_CallProc+0x699(71a45a8, 8afcf2c, 1109, 8c54f6c, 8ba5f54, 0)
  f1316778 _ctypes.so`CFuncPtr_call+0xe4(8b92f9c, 8afcf2c, 0, 7c798de)
  f13167b8 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyObject_Call+0x4b(8b92f9c, 8afcf2c, 0, 7d4f10e)
  f1316858 libpython2.6.so.1.0`call_function+0x349(f13168dc, 1, f4ade76f, 7d47e31)
  f1316908 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x872(8d4d244, 0, 8b823e4, 0)
  f1316948 libpython2.6.so.1.0`fast_function+0x118(8c4db54, f1316a7c, 1, 1, 0, 7db0000)
  f13169f8 libpython2.6.so.1.0`call_function+0x8e(f1316a7c, 1, f1316a48, 7d47e31)
  f1316aa8 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x872(8d4c5b4, 0, 8a8224c, 8a8224c)
  f1316b18 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x15f(8ad7218, 8a8224c, 8a8224c, 0, 0, 0)
  f1316b58 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyEval_EvalCode+0x32(8ad7218, 8a8224c, 8a8224c, 8a91e00)
  f1316b78 libpython2.6.so.1.0`run_mod+0x3a(8b47bd8, 7c5f9ac, 8a8224c, 8a8224c, f1316cdc)
  f1316bf8 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0x1a1(7ff5e90, 7c5f9ac, f1316cdc, 7d7866e)
  f1316c28 libpython2.6.so.1.0`PyRun_AnyFileExFlags+0x6b(7ff5e90, 7c5f9ac, 0, f1316cdc)
  f1316d88 libpython2.6.so.1.0`Py_Main+0x393(1, f1316df0, 7fb0895, 8050c2c)
  f1316db8 main+0x63(1, f1316df0, f1316df8)
  f1316de4 _start+0x77(1, f1316f38, 0, f1316f3f, f1316f5a, f1316f7e)
> ::regs
%cs = 0x0043            %eax = 0xb2b118f4 
%ds = 0x004b            %ebx = 0x071cb000 
%ss = 0x004b            %ecx = 0x08d95cc4 
%es = 0x004b            %edx = 0x00000000 
%fs = 0x0000            %esi = 0x00000000 
%gs = 0x01c3            %edi = 0x00000000 

 %eip = 0x07eb9520 libc_hwcap1.so.1`strlen+0x30
 %ebp = 0xf13165ac
%kesp = 0x00000000

%eflags = 0x00210246
  id=1 vip=0 vif=0 ac=0 vm=0 rf=1 nt=0 iopl=0x0
  status=<of,df,IF,tf,sf,ZF,af,PF,cf>

   %esp = 0xf1316360
%trapno = 0xe
   %err = 0x4
```

(says he, carefully choosing a single-threaded core he has lying around).

Now, as to `why` your process crashed - once you've got the thread stack you need to investigate your program source.